# pydantic: Reading model with values not in model

Tags: python, pydantic

Is it possible to define a model using pydantic that allows values not specified in the model?

For example I have a json object:

```
{
 "object_id": "x",
 "object_type": "some_type",
 "additional-key1": 1,
 "additional-key2": "abc"
}
```

and I want it to be defined using

```
class MyObject(BaseModel):
    object_id: str
    object_type: str
```

But retain all the other additional keys?

Answer (score 3):

yes

```py
class MyObject(BaseModel):
    object_id: str
    object_type: str

    class Config:
        extra = 'allow'
```

See [the docs on `Config`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/).